# Start at bottom then scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make my site animate from bottom to top on page load.

Like on this site: http://partnersandspade.com/studio/

The issue is that my site starts scrolling from halfway down on my site, not from the bottom.

What I have now is this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 0);
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 4000);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking jQuery to animate every time the user scrolls. And since this fires the scroll event:

`$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: x });`

You will scroll your page up and down endlessly.

Use imagesLoaded: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

```
// are those images loaded yet?
$('body').imagesLoaded(function() {
  var dh = $(document).height();

  // set the html, body to bottom while you're at opacity 0
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: dh }, 0);

  // transition to opacity 1
  $('body').addClass('loaded');

  // animate to the top
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 2000);
});
```

***Adding a Loading State***

To add a loading state I'd do something like this.

**CSS**

```
 body {
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: opacity: 0.5s;
   transition: opacity 0.5s;
 }
 body.loaded {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Comment: This adds a huge blank space on the top of my site, and doesn't animate at all. I added the `html, body { position: relative; }`

Comment: You can paste the contents of the function above in your console to verify that this works

Comment: It works when I enter (document).ready instead of (window).load, But now I see the problem, the sliders I have on the front page hasn't finished loading before it starts to scroll up, so I guess I should load the page 100% before lunching this script? How do I do that?

Comment: Yes because you're pasting it into your console, on a page that has already been loaded and all the assets have been accounted for and thus the doc height is the correct height. For your project if you use doc ready the document height variable will vary. You need to wait for all your assets to load.

Comment: I see.. But it's acting weird with (window).load also.. But like the site that I referred to in my post: http://partnersandspade.com/studio/ - They use a loader before the content is ready. I guess that could help. But how can I add that? If it's a lot more work, I can start a new question for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by acting weird, can you be more specific. I added a loading state example. You can get fancier than this but hopefully this will give you a good idea of the logic behind it

Comment: Yes, sorry. It seems like it doesn't scroll from the very bottom. 
It works perfectly fine when I run it from console after it's loaded.

This is a video showing how it acts with the code you posted now:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/asw5vn9zod3494i/AnimateOnLoad-01.mp4?dl=0

Comment: can you try adding https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded plugin and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: After including the imagesloaded.js on my site. Should I add some more code for that script anywhere?

Comment: Oh, that made sense! Thanks for describing the code so well :) But unfortunately the site is blank, like `opacity: 0;` kind of blank I think..

Comment: Yes, I replaced both js and css.. :S

Comment: I get this in console: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$('body').imagesLoaded')`

Comment: Put script for images loaded above everything else

Comment: Now I have these two errors left: `[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new EventEmitter()')
 factory (imagesloaded.js, line 125)
 (anonymous function) (imagesloaded.js, line 29)
 global code (imagesloaded.js, line 36)` and `[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$('body')')
 global code (animatesite.js, line 2)`

Comment: I'm calling in the scripts in this order: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3yml2zsqz6zljmn/Screenshot%202014-12-29%2020.44.22.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 0);
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);    
});
```

Here is the working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/xvafa479/

Comment: Yes, this should work. But I have a problem with this, because it doesn't scroll from the bottom. It starts way up there. The original code that I posted actually starts at the bottom with the same value (7000). I guess it has something to do with my site, because `$(document).height()` wasn't working either.

Comment: you can try to debug. Few tips:
1. alert for $(document).height() to check the value
2. decrease the speed of animation
`$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000);`

Comment: It returns 7454, and decreasing the animation speed doesn't help either.

Comment: Try to add a loading state. Do something like transitioning the opacity of html, body from 0 to 1 AFTER you've set the html, body offset top to whatever the height of the document is.

Comment: Sorry for being such a rookie. But I'm not sure how to do that. Can you show me an example? I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to watch the scroll event. you can simple remove it and start animation onload.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 7000 }, 0);
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000);
});
```

it will fire the animation only once.

Editted:

You can set the scroll to the end of the page. Like the other answers :

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 0);
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code you're posting here should be working just fine, but on my side, it doesn't start on the bottom, it appears to scroll from window height almost.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/ck52vb3k/ 
You just need to remove the scroll function on the animations

Code:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 7000 }, 0);  
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000); 
});
```